# Create time trigger with Google Script and spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, timer, google-apps-script

I want to create a simple time trigger to my sheet using Google Script, I do all like described in [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically), but when I call function I getting error:

```
Google Apps: You do not have permission to call newTrigger
```

I try to find solution in Internet but didn't get any results. Can somebody help me? Thanks!

P.S. My code:

```
 ScriptApp.newTrigger("consolius")
   .timeBased()
   .everyMinutes(1)
   .create();

function consolius() {
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Hello, world!');
}
```

Comment: Post the code generating the Trigger. Have you read all the limitations? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#limitations

Comment: @Kriggs, so how I get from this `Time-driven triggers cannot run more frequently than once per hour.` when I do this ScriptApp.newTrigger("consolius").timeBased().everyMinutes(1).create();`, so I cant do this? but exists method for run code every minute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The restrictions mentioned in comments do not apply to your use case, they are for [add-ons only](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#limitations). The right [info is here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers).

But even if you actually can create a timer trigger to run a function every minute you can not use the method you try because a timer trigger can't interact with the Ui.

If you look at the error notification you'll see that message :

```
Details:
Start   Function            Error Message                                            Trigger    End
7/3/15 4:08 PM  consolius   Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context. (line 26, file "clean sheet") time-based  7/3/15 4:08 PM
```

Another point of interest : you should include the script that creates the trigger in a function otherwise you will create a new trigger every time you run **ANY** other function in that project, including the function that the triggers calls, this will rapidly become quite messy ! (everything that is "global" is executed each time any function is called).

Last but not least : you can't use such code in a custom function, it has to be in a script you run from a menu or a button.